# How to differentiate between colors for the keywords "import" "def" and "try" in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, color-scheme, emacs24

I am new to emacs. I have started using the twilight theme for emacs from [here](https://github.com/developernotes/twilight-theme/blob/master/twilight-theme.el). But I get the same color for `import` `def` `class` `try` and `if` in python.(I have only tried python with this theme so far.)

However, I want a different set of colors for the following pairs:

- `import and from`
- `def and class`
- `try and if`.

I looked into the theme file and have figured out that the `font-lock-keyword-face` determines the color of the above keywords and those similar to them.

So how can I set different colors to the above pairs? Is there a way?

I am on emacs24. Whats wrong with my `.emacs`?

Comment: It's not the issue of the color theme. `python-mode` classifies all these words syntactically
as keywords. That's why they all have the same face and always will, until someone rewrites `python-mode`.
But I really like it the way it is now. There is a workaround to add your own regexp highlighting,
but that harms the editor responsiveness.

Comment: Also it's not good to ask two unrelated questions at once.

Comment: Yes, please split that second question into a second question (if you cannot find a duplicate with the search).

Comment: @abo-abo Thanks for that. But I looked up the same theme on sublime. `import` `class` and `try` have different colors. Whereas in vim, on a different theme, the colors for `import` and `class` are different.

Comment: And yes I will split it up now.

Comment: split the question. heres the new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374683/how-to-fix-symbols-function-definition-is-void-while-loading-up-a-color-theme

Answer (score 1):

Because `ALL` of the following keywords are defined within `python.el` as `python-font-lock-keywords`, you would need to trump some of them with a different font face or hack the source for these same keywords to have different font faces:

"and" "del" "from" "not" "while" "as" "elif" "global" "or" "with" "assert" "else" "if" "pass" "yield" "break" "except" "import" "class" "in" "raise" "continue" "finally" "is" "return" "def" "for" "lambda" "try" "print" "exec" "nonlocal" "self".

The following code is an example of how to trump `python-font-lock-keywords` for some of the keywords that have already been defined within `python.el` -- in this example, `while` is blue with **bold**; and, `for` is green with **bold** and *italics*.   `python-font-lock-keywords` that are not trumped by specially defined font faces will default to `font-lock-keyword-face` -- I have included a sample modification of that face as well:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
  '(font-lock-keyword-face
     ((t (:background "white" :foreground "red" :bold t))))
  )

(defvar lawlist-blue (make-face 'lawlist-blue))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-blue nil
  :background "white" :foreground "blue" :bold t)

(defvar lawlist-green (make-face 'lawlist-green))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-green nil
  :background "white" :foreground "green" :bold t :italic t)

(defvar lawlist-keywords-01
  (concat "\\b\\(?:"
    (regexp-opt (list "hello" "world" "while" ))
  "\\)\\b"))

(defvar lawlist-keywords-02
  (concat "\\b\\(?:"
    (regexp-opt (list "foo" "bar" "for" ))
  "\\)\\b"))

(font-lock-add-keywords 'python-mode (list

  (list (concat
    "\\("lawlist-keywords-01"\\)") 1 'lawlist-blue t)

  (list (concat
    "\\("lawlist-keywords-02"\\)") 1 'lawlist-green t)

   ))
```

Comment: Yes, the entire code gets inserted into the `.emacs` file -- go ahead and give it a try.  It's bedtime here now and I'll check back tomorrow to see if you have any follow-up questions.  It should work without any problems.

Comment: I think Im doing something wrong. Put the entire code in `.emacs` and added this `'(lawlist-keywords-01 ((t (:foreground "#000000"))))` to the `color-theme-twilight.el`. Not working. :(

Comment: The code in this answer was designed to be used inside the `.emacs` file.  Try it first without any modifications (e.g., by placing the entire code at the bottom of your `.emacs` file), and then restart Emacs, and then open up a python script and try using `while` and `for` to see the effect.  The code in this answer was **not** intended to be a modification of `color-theme-twilight.el`.  I just double checked my code and it works correctly.

Comment: I did that. Also I read that there should be only one instance of custom-set-faces. I have ensured there is only one. But it's still not working for some reason.

Comment: Based on this question / answer, and your other thread, it sounds like your Emacs installation has problems.  I would suggest backing it up somewhere and installing a new current version of Emacs -- i.e., start fresh.  Back-up and then delete or rename your `.emacs.d` folder also.  The code here should work -- if it doesn't work, then something is likely wrong with your Emacs installation.  If you are using a starter kit, then that may also be causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your .emacs. That's what font lock does: there's a handful of font lock targets--one for types, one for variables, one for keywords, etc. You can customize what face each one gets (e.g., M-x customize, then Faces, Font Lock, Font Lock Faces), and you can configure how each language matches regular expressions to targets. Since those are all keywords, they all get mapped to the keyword face.

If you really want to, you can edit the font-lock-keywords variable set by python-mode to match each keyword separately, and instead of just naming a font-lock target as your facespec, give a list (face FACE PROP VALUE ...), with as many props and values as you prefer. If you really want to do this, you really want to read the docs.

The full details are described in the manual section "Search-based Fontification" (23.6.2 in GNU emacs 23.4; maybe different in your version, but you can find it pretty easily from the Font Lock customize page).

Comment: How come vim distinguishes between `class` and `import` keywords?

Answer (score 0):

It's implemented here:

https://github.com/pdee/pdee

Code-base is basically that of python-mode.el, but comes with inlined Pymacs, company-mode, auto-completion

Or get it via bazaar:

```
bzr branch lp:python-mode/components-python-mode
```

which is the development-branch of python-mode.el